# How to configure Traefik with remote docker api to use remote host ip with natted ports

Tags: traefik

I am using Traefik 1.5.4 on a host separate from a docker host where i have containers running.  I can configure traefik to see the remote docker host and see the containers running, but all of the backend ips are of the container internal network ips.  These are not reachable from outside of the docker host.  I would like to configure traefik so that it knows to use the remote docker hosts routable ip with the containers natted port.